# ONVIF Application development for IP Cameras

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, onvif

I want to develop server using c# to stream ONVIF based IP cameras on any client like the website, mobile etc.I analyzed a lot of articles but I did not find anything without any sdk.

I want to develop this server without the third-party tool,sdk or API.

I study about ONVIF and found WSDL URLs on ONVIF official site.
But I don't have an idea, How should I have to start using WSDL URLs in .net using c#.

My first step is to search camera on the network or connect stream with the camera.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by studying these documents:
* [how to consume web services in c#](http://www.csharptutorial.in/37/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010)
* the [ONVIF Application Programmers Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf)

You will face at least two hard points: discovery and authentication. Sorry, I cannot give you any hint about tehm in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I know about web service consumption in c# and Onvif doc.Only problem is that from where i have to start like i want search all my Ip Cameras on my network.

Comment: I am getting an error regarding content type mismatch of request and response.Binding is based on SOAP12 protocol.

Comment: as I said, I am not expert of C#. Sorry.

Comment: maybe give a look at this link...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220574/how-to-generate-getsystemdateandtime-xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.. it didn't work for me, but i hope it'll work for you!

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1192709/ONVIF-PTZ-Control-in-Csharp

I have also no idea how to discover/authenticate to my cameras...

Comment: Thanks. But I am writing same code and its working in WPF but not in asp.net MVC controller.