# How to generate GetSystemDateAndTime xml

Tags: c#, wsdl, visual-studio-2017, onvif

I have the following bit of code that i took from [this source](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1192709/ONVIF-PTZ-Control-in-Csharp)...

```
public bool Initialise(string cameraAddress, string userName, string password)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
            {
                MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
            };

            HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
            };

            CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messageElement, httpBinding);


            mediaClient = new MediaClient(bind, new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/Media"));
            mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = userName;
            mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;

            var profs = mediaClient.GetProfiles();

            //rest of the code...
```

When i run wireshark while going through the `GetProfiles()` part in the debugger, I see that the generated XML looks like:

[image: xml0]

What code would it take to change the xml to look like:

[image: xml1]

How am i supposed to call the `GetSystemDateAndTime` function?

To call the `GetProfiles` function, I had to create a `MediaClient` and, then, call that function...

Is there such thing as a MediaClient to get access to the GetSystemDateAndTime??

**Edit:**

I found that you could use the `DeviceClient` to get access the the `GetSystemDateAndTime` function...

You'll need to add the device management wsdl to your connected services before:
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

I also added `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` in there because i saw someone said it helped at [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1192709/ONVIF-PTZ-Control-in-Csharp?msg=5408881#xx5408881xx)...

So i added :

```
CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messageElement, httpBinding);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
DeviceClient d = new DeviceClient(bind, new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/device_service"));
var time = d.GetSystemDateAndTime();
```

**Note:**
I'm still getting the error:

```
        ErrorMessage    "The header 'To' from the namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding. "   string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is saying that there is trouble when trying to read a message, so i tough it was probably due to some sort of encoding ...

AND I WAS RIGHT!!

All I had to do was changing a parameter in the `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement`'s creation.

```
MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10)
```

All you need to do is make sure that you have good **encoding** and **AuthenticationScheme**...

Here's my final code to get an onvif camera's (here cohuHD camera) system and date and time settings:

```
public bool Initialise(string cameraAddress, string userName, string password)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
            {
                MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10)
            };

            HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
            };

            CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messageElement, httpBinding);

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            DeviceClient deviceClient = new DeviceClient(bind, new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/device_service"));

            var temps = deviceClient.GetSystemDateAndTime();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Bonus:**

If you want to execute a function that needs credentials, you can add those to your deviceClient like so:

```
//DIGEST (httpBinding)
deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = userName;
deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;
```

Watch out also for the `EndpointAddress`' URL... I think some cameras use Device_service and other device_service .