# How do I create a live video recording program on Visual Studio using c#?

Tags: c#, video-capture, ip-camera

I am currently doing a project for school and desperately in need of help.

The main gist of the project:

- I am using 3 Bosch Dinion IP Cameras to film students during a lecture. I have to create a program on Visual Studio that enables the lecturer to view all 3 cameras on one screen, able to record all 3 footages and then save them in a database afterwards.
- The thing about Bosch is that there is very limited material for me to refer to online.

I have already referred to SDKs from Bosch and Ozeki but I can't seem to figure out the codes. I sought help from a few people and they told me to use Onvif (I am unsure how to use it).

I would greatly appreciate all of the help I could get, and if possible explained in simple terms. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have to code every single bit or you can use 3rd party SDKs or open source components?

Comment: Yes I am. But the problem is that Bosch SDK *does* allow me to view all 3 cameras with the appropriate frame rate but doesn't have the record feature, while the Ozeki SDK has the record feature but has terrible fps & will only record a few seconds of the footage and turn to a blank screen with its trademark at the end.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Don't be alarmed if you're downvoted for this question, it's just the community trying to vet the posts and have good questions. Please read over [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), produce a [complete, minimal and verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This is a programming Q/A site, not a software referral one. If you have a code issue, *please* provide code for it. As it stands, this question violates some of our guidelines. Too vague.

Comment: Another thing to note is that this is course work designed to *help you learn how to code*. If at first you don't succeed, try and try again. Look over the documentation, speak to your lecturer and see if you can get a good baseline application. Baby steps. Make a flow chart. Make some empty functions and figure out application flow. Tinker with the external SDK's in a separate project. Stuff like that.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Visual Studio, which is a code editor. Please remove the `visual-studio` tag.

Comment: @siberiangold as you pointet out, Ozeki SDK only allows you to record a few seconds and has bad quality. I think this is due to a test version because they want you to buy the software. When you are already able to record you should consider to buy it. You mentioned you use it for school. Some companies offer great education discount or even give the software away for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can view and record the Bosch Dinion camera with the [TVideoGrabber SDK](http://www.datastead.com/products/tvideograbber.html) and this sample code:

```
VideoGrabber1.VideoSource = vs_IPCamera
VideoGrabber1.IPCameraURL = "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.34/rtsp_tunnel?h26x=4&line=1&inst=1"
VideoGrabber1.RecordingMethod = rm_MP4
VideoGrabber1.RecordingFileName = "c:\folder\filename.mp4"
VideoGrabber1.StartRecording()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ONVIF (Open Network Video Interface Forum) is a global and open industry forum with the goal of facilitating the development and use of a global open standard for the interface of physical IP-based security products – or, in other words, to create a standard for how IP products within video surveillance and other physical security areas can communicate with each other. ONVIF is an organization started in 2008 by Axis Communications, Bosch Security Systems and Sony.

Thanks wikipedia^

At first, you should try to establish a connection to your camera using the OnvifDeviceManager (disponible at this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/))

The OnvifDeviceManager is a tool made to test if your camera is ONVIF conformant.

If you're able to get a video feed/ptz control of your camera, it means it shouldn't be that hard to make an app for your needs.

There's two part to the app you want to make:

1) Communicating to the camera.

2) Showing/recording the video stream

In part 1 you want to be able to send request to your camera and get responses from it. You could use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220574/how-to-generate-getsystemdateandtime-xml) to make your first ONVIF request to one of your camera... You'll then want to get the stream URL with a request you'll make

In part 2 you want to take the streaming link you'll get from your request and show it somewhere with some tools... I personally used VLC.DOTNET to add a vlcControl to my C# form and show the stream of my camera. There's help to do so on this [link](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Using-Vlc.DotNet-in-WinForms).

Good luck, have fun developing your app!

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for this! It helped me a lot and I already have the first part figured out. As for the second part, is there any source code (from a pre-existing project) that you referred to while doing it? I'm currently struggling trying to make a mosaic on c# with all my cameras and get the app to record all the footages and save it to the database.

Comment: This is the [getting started guide](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Getting-started) to vlc.dotnet. You can start by looking through it... Try to make some code and if something is not working as intended, try to ask more specific questions! We need code to help you... If you're trying to make a mosaic with the feed of all your cameras, you only need to add more vlc controls to your form hahah.... There's also some recording function disponible with libvlc... Maybe you can ask on the [vlc forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=32) for some more help....