# AXIS camera possible with java?

Tags: java, interface, onvif

I was wondering if its possible to create an interface on java of an AXIS camera working with ONVIF...

I just don't know how i can recognize my cam with java cause it doesn't work at all, somebody has an idea or could help me do that?

Just the beginning that i know it is recognizing my cam, I should be able then to do the other stuff later on.
Well I dont know if it's even possible to do this, if someone knows more about it just tell me please.

I already tried a few times just as I said before, but there is no reaction of the camera.
Thanks.

Comment: at first, you should try to use the ONVIF device manager to see if your camera is onvif conformant. [download here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/) then i would suggest you to see the answer i gave to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732384/how-do-i-create-a-live-video-recording-program-on-visual-studio-using-c/50744862#50744862) question to help you start with a basic application

Comment: @LoukMo did you do all this stuff? I just saw it and I'll try to do it tomorrow, but can I ask you something? cause I don't see how to write you private in here...would you might helping me in the process to recognize it ? I'm not enought good in this stuff i guess and i have to do it. Just if you want and have enough time :) and thanks btw for your quick answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you much more with your problem... The only thing I can say is try to copycat the OnvifDeviceManager... If you have any more specific questions about how to code things, ask them as another question and many people will gladly be able to help you out! Best of luck with your application!

Comment: what type of document do you use in Visual Studio to become like the response? I dont get it...and how should my XMAL code look like to open the window so I can see the live stream?

Comment: Give a look at this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1192709/ONVIF-PTZ-Control-in-Csharp)... This is what helped me starting my onvif camera project! (:

It tells you how to add references to a ONVIF wsdl to your c# project and how to make a simple PTZ request.

Comment: yeah...I tried that but I dont know what kind of file i can open it with...because its not a wpf file right?